# Visual Studio - Cordova App - Buildproblem

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, phonegap-build, visual-studio-cordova

I want to start with a new blank cordova app in visual studio.

I´ve created a new project. Now I want to build the generated project and I get the following error.

Diagnostic output:

```
... 
CopyToOutputDirectory=Never
                DestinationRelativePath=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js.map
Die Erstellung des Ziels "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" im Projekt "Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" ist abgeschlossen.: (Ziel-ID:18)
Ziel "CompileTypeScript: (Ziel-ID:19)" in Datei "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" aus Projekt "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" (Ziel "BuildRipple" ist davon abhängig):
Das Ziel "CompileTypeScript" wird vollständig erstellt.
Es wurden keine Eingabedateien angegeben.
VsTsc-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:ToolExe=tsc.exe (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:Configurations= --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError --locale de-DE --project "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung" --out "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js" (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:YieldDuringToolExecution=True (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:OutFile=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:ProjectDir=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\ (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Aufgabenparameter:ToolsVersion=1.4 (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
  Ausgegebene Elemente:
      GeneratedJavascript=
          C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js
                  DestinationRelativePath=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js
          C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js.map
                  DestinationRelativePath=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\www\scripts\appBundle.js.map (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
Ausführen der VsTsc-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 17)
Die Erstellung des Ziels "CompileTypeScript" im Projekt "Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" ist abgeschlossen.: (Ziel-ID:19)
Ziel "PrepareForRippleRequirements: (Ziel-ID:20)" in Datei "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" aus Projekt "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" (Ziel "BuildRipple" ist davon abhängig):
CallTarget-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 18)
  Aufgabenparameter:Targets=EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion (Aufgaben-ID: 18)
Ziel "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion: (Ziel-ID:21)" in Datei "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" aus Projekt "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" (Ziel "PrepareForRippleRequirements" ist davon abhängig):
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ('$(ProjectDir.Substring(0, 2))' == '\\') wurde als ('C:' == '\\') ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And $(NodeJsDir) == '') wurde als (true == 'true' And C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ == '') ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') wurde als (true == 'true' And C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools == '') ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(NodeJsDir) == '') wurde als (true == '' And C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ == '') ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') wurde als (true == '' And C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools == '') ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . (!Exists('$(NodeJsDir)') Or !Exists('$(NodeJsDir)\node.exe')) wurde als (!Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\') Or !Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe')) ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . (!Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)') Or !Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)\packages\vs-tac')) wurde als (!Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools') Or !Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac')) ausgewertet.
CallTarget-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 19)
  Aufgabenparameter:Targets=InstallMDA (Aufgaben-ID: 19)
Ziel "InstallMDA: (Ziel-ID:22)" in Datei "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" aus Projekt "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" (Ziel "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" ist davon abhängig):
Die RunMdaInstall-Aufgabe aus der C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll-Assembly wird verwendet.
RunMdaInstall-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:MdaVsixDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:NodeInstallPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:NpmInstallDir=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:LangName=de-DE (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:ProjectDir=. (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:Configuration=Debug (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Aufgabenparameter:PackageName=vs-tac (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (x64) and npm. (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ------ Korrekte globale Installation des Pakets aus dem Quellpaketverzeichnis wird sichergestellt: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ------ Name aus Quelle "package.json": vs-tac (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ------ Version aus Quelle "package.json": 0.2.19 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ------ Paket ist aktuell nicht global installiert. (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ------ Globale Installation aus Quellpaket. Das kann einige Minuten dauern ... (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"}) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.6.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"}) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  vs-tac@0.2.19 C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── rimraf@2.2.6 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── ncp@0.5.1 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── q@1.0.1 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── semver@2.3.1 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── fstream@0.1.28 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.6) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── adm-zip@0.4.4 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── elementtree@0.1.6 (sax@0.3.5) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── request@2.36.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.3, http-signature@0.10.1, form-data@0.1.4, tough-cookie@1.1.0, hawk@1.0.0) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.28 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, colors@0.6.0-1, open@0.0.3, accounting@0.4.1, request@2.12.0, moment@1.7.2, express@3.1.0) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  └── plugman@0.22.4 (q@0.9.7, nopt@1.0.10, underscore@1.4.4, rc@0.3.0, cordova-lib@0.21.6, npm@1.3.4) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  ------ npm-Installation von vs-tac@0.2.19 aus C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac abgeschlossen. (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Ausgegebene Eigenschaft: MDAInstallErrorCode=-17 (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
  Ausgegebene Eigenschaft: CordovaVersion= (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
Ausführen der RunMdaInstall-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
CallTarget-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 21)
  Aufgabenparameter:Targets=MDACleanAfterInstall (Aufgaben-ID: 21)
Ziel "MDACleanAfterInstall: (Ziel-ID:23)" in Datei "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" aus Projekt "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" (Ziel "InstallMDA" ist davon abhängig):
CallTarget-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 22)
  Aufgabenparameter:Targets=CleanCordovaDeploy (Aufgaben-ID: 22)
Das Ziel "CleanCordovaDeploy" wurde übersprungen. Die vorherige Erstellung war erfolgreich.
Ausführen der CallTarget-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 22)
Die RemoveDir-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . (Exists('%(Identity)')) wurde als (Exists('bld\iOS\Debug')) ausgewertet.
Die RemoveDir-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . (Exists('%(Identity)')) wurde als (Exists('bld\Ripple\iOS\Debug')) ausgewertet.
Die RemoveDir-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . (Exists('%(Identity)')) wurde als (Exists('bin\iOS\Debug')) ausgewertet.
Die Erstellung des Ziels "MDACleanAfterInstall" im Projekt "Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" ist abgeschlossen.: (Ziel-ID:23)
Ausführen der CallTarget-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 21)
WriteLinesToFile-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 23)
  Aufgabenparameter:File=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\\platforms\cli-version (Aufgaben-ID: 23)
  Aufgabenparameter:Overwrite=True (Aufgaben-ID: 23)
  Aufgabenparameter:Encoding=Unicode (Aufgaben-ID: 23)
Ausführen der WriteLinesToFile-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 23)
Die Delete-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) == '-17' AND Exists('bld\iOS\Debug\buildInfo.json')) wurde als (-17 == '-17' AND Exists('bld\iOS\Debug\buildInfo.json')) ausgewertet.
Die Error-Aufgabe wurde übersprungen, da die Bedingung "false" war . ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '0' And $(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '-17') wurde als (-17 != '0' And -17 != '-17') ausgewertet.
Die Erstellung des Ziels "InstallMDA" im Projekt "Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" ist abgeschlossen.: (Ziel-ID:22)
Ausführen der CallTarget-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 19)
Die Erstellung des Ziels "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" im Projekt "Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" ist abgeschlossen.: (Ziel-ID:21)
Ausführen der CallTarget-Aufgabe beendet. (Aufgaben-ID: 18)
Die MdaVsCli-Aufgabe aus der C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll-Assembly wird verwendet.
MdaVsCli-Aufgabe (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:NpmInstallDir=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:Platform=Android (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:ProjectDir=. (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:Configuration=Debug (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:ProjectName=Raumvisualisierung (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:Language=de-DE (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:BuildTarget=RippleNexus (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  Aufgabenparameter:PackageName=vs-tac (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
   (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung>"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd"   prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName Raumvisualisierung --npmInstallDir C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm --language de-DE  (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------ Cordova-Tools cordova@4.3.0 für Projekt werden von npm installiert. Dieser Vorgang kann einige Minuten dauern ... (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  cordova@4.3.0 cordova (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ├── underscore@1.7.0 (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ├── q@1.0.1 (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  └── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, d8@0.4.4, elementtree@0.1.5, glob@4.0.6, request@2.47.0, init-package-json@1.4.2, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.8.0, npm@1.3.4) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
   (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------ npm-Installation von cordova@4.3.0 aus npm abgeschlossen. (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------ Build Settings: (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------ Build Settings: (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\bld\Android\Debug (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\bin\Android\Debug (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    buildCommand: prepare (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    platform: Android (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    cordovaPlatform: android (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    configuration: Debug (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    projectName: Raumvisualisierung (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------    language: de-DE (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  ------ Plattform wird hinzugefügt: android (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml... (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1 (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\lockfile\lockfile.js:46 (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
        throw er (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
              ^ (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
  TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters. (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:117:25) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:80:8) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at Request.start (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:594:30) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
      at Request.end (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:1186:28) (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
Die Ausführung der MdaVsCli-Aufgabe ist abgeschlossen -- FEHLER. (Aufgaben-ID: 24)
Die Erstellung des Ziels "PrepareForRippleRequirements" im Projekt "Raumvisualisierung.jsproj" ist abgeschlossen -- FEHLER.: (Ziel-ID:20)

Leistungszusammenfassung für das Projekt:
    82715 ms C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung\Raumvisualisierung.jsproj   1 Aufrufe
              82715 ms rebuild                                    1 Aufrufe

Leistungszusammenfassung für das Ziel:
        0 ms BeforeBuild                                1 Aufrufe
        0 ms CleanReferencedProjects                    1 Aufrufe
        0 ms CoreBuild                                  1 Aufrufe
        0 ms _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     1 Aufrufe
        0 ms _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 Aufrufe
        0 ms AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 Aufrufe
        0 ms AfterClean                                 1 Aufrufe
        0 ms _BeforeBeforeRebuild                       1 Aufrufe
        0 ms CleanPublishFolder                         1 Aufrufe
        0 ms BeforeClean                                1 Aufrufe
        0 ms BuildOnlySettings                          1 Aufrufe
        0 ms BeforeRebuild                              1 Aufrufe
        0 ms Clean                                      1 Aufrufe
        0 ms CleanCordovaDeploy                         1 Aufrufe
        0 ms MDACleanAfterInstall                       1 Aufrufe
        0 ms AfterBuild                                 1 Aufrufe
       16 ms CoreClean                                  1 Aufrufe
       32 ms CompileTypeScript                          1 Aufrufe
      109 ms PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 Aufrufe
    41098 ms InstallMDA                                 1 Aufrufe
    41113 ms EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 Aufrufe
    82559 ms PrepareForRippleRequirements               1 Aufrufe

Leistungszusammenfassung für die Aufgabe:
        0 ms Message                                    2 Aufrufe
        0 ms RemoveDuplicates                           1 Aufrufe
        0 ms RemoveDir                                  1 Aufrufe
        0 ms FindUnderPath                              2 Aufrufe
        0 ms AssignTargetPath                           1 Aufrufe
        0 ms WriteLinesToFile                           2 Aufrufe
        0 ms ReadLinesFromFile                          1 Aufrufe
        0 ms AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 Aufrufe
        0 ms Delete                                     2 Aufrufe
        0 ms MakeDir                                    1 Aufrufe
       78 ms VsTsc                                      2 Aufrufe
    41098 ms RunMdaInstall                              1 Aufrufe
    41446 ms MdaVsCli                                   1 Aufrufe
    82212 ms CallTarget                                 5 Aufrufe

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

Verstrichene Zeit 00:01:22.69
========== Alles neu erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

Full version:

http://www.filedropper.com/dokument

Comment: Set the build output to diagnostic (Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project build output verbosity) and do a clean build.  That will provide more useful information about the failure.  You can post the relevant failure information from the build output to get recommendations on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Thans for your answer. I added the build output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem even with an empty Apache Cordova template project on VS2015 RC. I managed to fix the problem though.
If you look at your build output you can see the following two lines.

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"}) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)

npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.6.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"}) (Aufgaben-ID: 20)
```

I also had the same two lines. It says it wants different node version (0.10.x). I checked my node version and it was v0.12.2. I can see that your node version is also v0.12.2 based on your build output. But the VS2015 RC originally installed nodeJS v0.10.33 32 bit edition with "Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova". Actually I had to install v0.12.2 of NodeJS for some other non VS work after that. That caused this problem in the VS. I tried to fix this problem by pointing to v0.10.33 of NodeJS instead of v0.12.2 using NVM. But I was not successful. Hence I had to do the following. They were the only steps required to fix the problem.

1) I uninstalled NodeJS using Add/Remove programs as Visual Studio 2015 RC did not like that version.

2) After that I installed v0.10.33 NodeJS by clicking "Joyent Node.js" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551(v=vs.140).aspx.

3) Finally I reset vs-tac and set the proxies as stated in "https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551%20(v=vs.140).aspx#Proxy". I am also behind a corporate proxy.

Those steps fixed the problem.

Comment: Beware of interpreting an "npm WARN" as an error; especially when "current" version is newer than "wanted".  It is unlikely that you need to wind back to 0.10.x from 0.12.x.  It is more likely that step 3 was the problem - I would take a look in my global node module folder first and see if all required modules (vs-tac specifically, in this case) are installed before you start downgrading anything.  (Please note this comment is made after VS2015 RTM so this original answer from @Kushil could've been completely correct with the betas/RC versions)

Comment: I checked for vs-tac before downgrading. It was there in %AppData%\npm\node_modules. I also re-installed vs-tac before downgrading node.js. But it did not work. That is why I had to take the above mentioned actions.As you mentioned this may only be related to VS2015 RC. I haven't run node 0.12.x with VS2015 RTM to do a cordova project.

Answer (score 0):

The build error "TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters"
indicates that you are operating behind a proxy.  You need to configure proxy settings for the npm package manager.  Follow the instructions in the documentation [Configure tools to work with a proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551%20(v=vs.140).aspx#Proxy).

Comment: Yes, I´m behind a proxy.
I repeat the proxy-settings with your instructions but I get an error again.

I updated the output in my question.